# How to send approval email request in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

How to send Email approval request from Campaign form in Ms Dynamics CRM.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you asking how to send an offer to all members of a marketing list?

Comment: Are you referring to Quick Campaign? I'm still not clear on what the problem is. Please elaborate.

Comment: I went to Campaign (the normal one), created an instance of it and targeted it with a marketing list. Where is the problem?

Comment: thx @ Viltersten , actually  what i want is, if i send one offer to an particular member asking for approval by selecting "Send for Approval" , in list of options ,  then if  destination member accepts that mail and if approved , then i need to get reply message as approved.
Actually im new to CRM , i dont know how to elaborate this.

Comment: see the screen shot above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittably, I'm very tired now because I've been up all night but as far I can see, I can't find **your** set of options. This is what it looks like on my machine (RU 12, on-premise).

[image]

Comment: yeah ok Viltersten , may i know how to work with this? For Eg Sending "ready to launch" to some other user and he accepts as completed... For this is it necessary  to assign to some one else or some thing else?

Comment: When you launch a campaign and a targeted recipient chooses to accept, you should get in into the CRM as an instance of entity *CampaignResponse*. If you need to create an email (or anything else for that matter) upon that, I'd suggest a plugin that fires on *Create* message of it. Is it clearer now?   :)